# After upgrade to Lubuntu 20.04 sound ONLY wotking with aplay in root. And when Pulseaudio is removed it works as User

Tags: sound, lubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa

I recently upgraded to Lubuntu 20.04.  And -as has happened before- NO SOUND!.  I went through all the ask-ubuntu-forum entries and tried and tried - many times and many suggested solutions.

The result is:

- without pulseaudio installed, I have aplay playing audio as root and as user.
- with pulseaudio installed aplay only plays as root.

I never got any sound from VLC or Youtube to my speakers as you can't easily run firefox or vlc as root. And if I deinstall pulseaudio there is no sound either.

I edited /etc/group to add my user to the audio: and pulse: and pulse-access: groups - did not change anything.
I am pretty sure this is a privilege issue, as the thing works in root.

Just for info: pavucontrol shows my built-in digital stereo (IEC958) and tells that the digital output (S/PDIF) is the port - I use the analog line-out. I do not think this is an issue as there is sound from aplay when I sudo into root. But I see the bars on the playback tab (firefox) and on the output devices moving - like there is music. However this does not make it to the speakers...?

Quite frankly I am asking myself why the Lubuntu/Ubuntu developers make life so damned difficult?

Any further suggestions or fixes are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

got it to work.  Key is to select in the "Configuration" tab from pavucontrol the right output  and then on the Output device the analog line out outputs.  Disregard all the 'unavailable' messages...

BUT, I am totally flabbergasted that this selection is NOT sticky after reboots - given the pretty long list of possibilities I see in the Configuration tab.  PulseAudio needs some SIGNIFICANT improvement to add a button to save the current configuration - and not try to guess on boot each and every time the wrong stuff.  Sorry too much geeks here and no clue about user interface and user friendliness.